# Why is my Symfony2 @UniqueEntity constraint not working at all?

Tags: symfony, constraints

I have the following entity class in my application:

```
<?php

namespace ...;

// use ...
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;;
// ...

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="sc_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email", "username"})
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable, EquatableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration"})
     * @Assert\Email(groups={"registration"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string $username
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=32, unique=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration"})
     */
    private $username;

    // ...
}
```

The @UniqueEntity constraint is being ignored. I tried different flavors including:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"email", "username"})
```

and

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"email"})
@UniqueEntity(fields={"username"})
```

and, as per the Symfony2 documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

```
@UniqueEntity("email")
@UniqueEntity("username")
```

Nothing I do, works. Instead of getting a form validation error as expected, I am getting the following exception:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'admin@scire.com' for key 'UNIQ_D8183973E7927C74'

This is just wrong! Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem was solved as follows:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, groups={"registration"})
@UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, groups={"registration"})
```

The registration groups were missing, and I needed to separate them into two separate annotations.

Comment: Hi there Josef, seems a bit of an old question, but I'm having the same issue as you had - just wondering - did you need to, I dunno, __create__ that validation group somewhere? I added the unique entity field exactly as you did, only on email and cellphone, but it's still giving me an exception instead of a validation error. Any ideas?

Comment: @iLikeBreakfast you need to declare the validation group in your `setDefaultOptions` method in your `FormType`

Comment: Why is this solution different than what is indicated on the documentation? Is the documentation wrong, or is this implementation significantly different than the documentation example?http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Answer (score 14):

Another reason for this issue is if you are using form collections and include a sub-form which handles an associated entity, you have to set `cascade_validation` to `true` in the root and all sub-forms.

See the hint in the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms):

> To activate validation on CategoryType, add the `cascade_validation` option to `TaskType`:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ));
}
```

**Update:**

To ensure that your child entities are validated there is even a better way. Symfony provides the `Valid` constraint for exactly this reason. From [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html):

> **Valid**
>   This constraint is used to enable validation on objects that are embedded as properties on an object being validated. This allows you to validate an object and all sub-objects associated with it.

Answer (score 4):

Please note ignoreNull

For example to work correctly with pid (can be null):

```
constraints:
- Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
  fields: [page, pid, position]
  errorPath: page
  groups: [Menu]
  message: "Page already exists with that parent"
  ignoreNull: false
```

Comment: That was the answer for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
framework:
    validation:
        enable_annotations: true
```

to your app configuration